Clustered/ non clustered index on composite index
I have this create table query
 create table some(
  someid bigint not null,
        

Thank you

InnoDB has no option for declaring which index to use as the clustered index.
The clustered index of an InnoDB table is always chosen in this order:

The PRIMARY KEY
The first non-null UNIQUE KEY
A generated internal key. See my answer here: InnoDB: Find clustered index in existing table. In your example, this would be the clustered index, because your table has no PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY.

